# XSS - кавычка вначале

Tags: php, javascript, xss

скажите, что означает кавычка и знак больше вначале следующего кода?

```
"><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

почему эти знаки ставятся таким образом, приведите пример с какой фильтрацией проходит такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое проходит, если вы на странице делаете вывод сразу в `HTML` тег, например в атрибут. Вот такой код вставит тег скрипт в `HTML` и загрузит вредоносный `JS` код:

```
<a href="<?= $_POST['link']; ?>">Ссылка</a>
```

На выходе получим `HTML` код:

```
<a href=""><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>">Ссылка</a>
```

Что и вызовет выполнение `JS` скрипта.

Что бы избежать такого, удаляете теги через [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) или преобразуйте все теги в специальные сущности [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Можно обойти strip_tags() так " onmousemove = "alert(document.coockie); а htmlspecialchars(); превращает & в &amp; к примеру что не очень хорошо. filter_var()

Comment: да, поэтому лучше вообще пользовательский ввод не выводить в атрибутах тегов

Comment: В общем то тема обширная, не выводить конечно одно из лучших решений.